# Push ViewController from Right To Left with UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

As everyone know the UINavigationController push a ViewController from Left To Right, is there a way to push the View from Right To Left? like the animation for the back button.
For now I have this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can create a `NSMutableArray` from the navigationController's array of `viewcontrollers` and insert new viewController before the current one. Then set the viewControllers array without animation and pop back.

```
UIViewController *newVC = ...;
NSMutableArray *vcs =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
[vcs insertObject:newVC atIndex:[vcs count]-1];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcs animated:NO];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: Interesting approach. Could work, though likely to come with some headscratching.

Comment: sound kind of interesting. I need to pass somes informations inside the ViewController so maybe it can work with this way.Can you show me how I can insert my new ViewController before the current one?

Comment: I have added a code snippet, illustrating this approach. This is definitely not in line with the HIG and will likely confuse users. But it should do what you requested. I didn't test that though.

Comment: thats perfect, just need to change [vsc indexOfObject:self] by this one [vsc count] -1

Comment: I created a working subclass of UINavigationController based on this idea: http://bit.ly/iOS-rtl

Comment: get only one problem, if i click on the row, I move back, BUT i have "Back" button in left top corner, so i have to click "back" to empty array or something like that

Comment: You would probably need to set a different back bar button item for all view controllers and implement your own navigation logic.

Comment: The problem is when I want to get back to the view that I came from, I need to initialize it once again, he reborn and the viewDidLoad is called, a thing I don't want to do. How can it be fixed?

Comment: The resulting animation is not the same a 'from left' animation that would have the view coming from the left _over_ the current view.

Comment: So hacky. Using CATransition should be the right approach.

Comment: It is definitely hacky. Both in terms of the code and the confusing user experience.

Answer (score 37):

Please try this one

```
HomePageController  *pageView = [[HomePageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomePageController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.45;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionDefault];
transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
transition.delegate = self;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pageView animated:NO];
```

Comment: why do you set the type of the transition twice?

Comment: The type should be kCATransitionPush and the subtype kCATransitionFromLeft. It's redundant to set the type twice. I'll edit the answer

Answer (score 10):

```
Try this :  
//Push effect in reverse way
    CATransition* transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.75;
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush;
    transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
    [self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:kCATransition];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 6):

This code is working fine. Please try

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
transition.duration = 0.3f;
transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
transition.type = kCATransitionReveal;
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:phoneServicesViewController animated:NO];
```

Comment: Finally! I have been trying for hours and none have worked until yours.

Comment: @TriannaBrannon glad to hear that code snippets were helpful for you.

Answer (score 2):

No, right to left is reserved for popping viewcontrollers from the navigation stack. You can however get such an effect by animating the views yourself. Something like:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"rightToLeft" context:NULL];
CGRect newFrame = aView.frame;
newFrame.origin.x -= newFrame.size.width;
aView.frame = newFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This will however not do anything to your navigation controller.

Comment: good to know, and how to do it if I pop the View From the navigation Stack?

Comment: @Ludo: you can't pop views from the navigation stack. the "stack" contains viewcontrollers

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I typed views, but of course had viewcontrollers in mind. How to pop a viewcontroller is explained by the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to "pop back". This can be achieved by three methods on your `UINavigationController` instance:

To come back to the "root" controller:

`-(NSArray *)popToRootViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`

Or to come back to one of the previous controllers :

`-(NSArray *)popToViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated`

Or to come back to the previously pushed controller :

`-(UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated`

Comment: thanks that help, I just wanna try the Felix's answer but don't really know how to do it

Answer (score 2):

Just an improvement of the best answer here in my opinion:

```
UIViewController *newVC = ...;
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:@[newVC, self] animated:NO];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

And to go back to the initial controller, just do a push to it.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @felixlam 's answer, I upgraded and created a "reverse" direction navigation controller that overrides the default push / pop methods to act like this.

```
class LeftPushNavigationController: BaseNavigationController {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    interactivePopGestureRecognizer?.isEnabled = false
  }

  override func pushViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    // If the push is not animated, simply pass to parent
    guard animated else { return super.pushViewController(viewController, animated: animated) }

    // Setup back button
    do {
      // Hide original back button
      viewController.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
      // Add new one
      viewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
        image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "iconBackReverse"),
        style: .plain,
        target: self,
        action: #selector(self.pop)
      )
    }

    // Calculate final order
    let finalVCs = self.viewControllers + [viewController]

    // Insert the viewController to the before-last position (so it can be popped to)
    var viewControllers = self.viewControllers
    viewControllers.insert(viewController, at: viewControllers.count - 1)

    // Insert viewcontroller before the last one without animation
    super.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: false)
    // Pop with the animation
    super.popViewController(animated: animated)
    // Set the right order without animation
    super.setViewControllers(finalVCs, animated: false)
  }

  override func popViewController(animated: Bool) -> UIViewController? {
    // If the push is not animated, simply pass to parent
    guard animated else { return super.popViewController(animated: animated) }

    guard self.viewControllers.count > 1 else { return nil }

    // Calculate final order
    var finalVCs = self.viewControllers
    let viewController = finalVCs.removeLast()

    // Remove the parent ViewController (so it can be pushed)
    var viewControllers = self.viewControllers
    let parentVC = viewControllers.remove(at: viewControllers.count - 2)

    // Set the viewcontrollers without the parent & without animation
    super.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: false)
    // Create push animation with the parent
    super.pushViewController(parentVC, animated: animated)
    // Set the right final order without animation
    super.setViewControllers(finalVCs, animated: false)

    // Return removed viewController
    return viewController
  }

  @objc
  private func pop() {
    _ = popViewController(animated: true)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 5.0**

```
 let pageView = TaskFolderListViewController.init(nibName: "HomePageController_iPhone", bundle: nil)
 let transition = CATransition()
 transition.duration = 0.45
 transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.default)
 transition.type = CATransitionType.push
 transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft
 self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(pageView, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, this is how I solved it

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

This will resemble "going back" i.e a situation where a back button is clicked and you navigate to the previous page

Answer (score 0):

Based on previous best answers, you can make `UINavigationController` extension and preserve the navigation stack as follows:

```
extension UINavigationController {
    /// Pushes view controller into navigation stack with backwards animation.
    func pushBackwards(viewController newViewController: UIViewController) {
        if let currentController = viewControllers.last {
            let previousControllers = viewControllers[0..<viewControllers.endIndex-1]
            var controllers = Array(previousControllers + [newViewController, currentController])
            setViewControllers(controllers, animated: false)
            popViewController(animated: true)
            // Adjusting the navigation stack
            _ = controllers.popLast()
            controllers.insert(currentController, at: controllers.count-1)
            setViewControllers(controllers, animated: false)
        } else {
            // If there is no root view controller, set current one without animation.
            setViewControllers([newViewController], animated: false)
        }
    }
}
```