# Can't push viewController after "Popping" it

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I've got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2415772/push-viewcontroller-from-right-to-left-with-uinavigationcontroller) and it works perfectly as I needed. but the problem is when I want to pop the view controller and get back to the main screen. when I uses

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

it's not doing nothing. but when I use the same code it works, but not as the way I want, from 'Left to Right'.

This is the code, what I have to do in order to make it pop back the view controller in the same direction he came from? I understands that it puts the viewController before the one I'm working on and than pop's it, but now how can I push? when I try to push I get  error.

```
    NSMutableArray *vcs =  [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    [vcs insertObject:levelsView atIndex:[vcs count]-1];
    [self.navigationController setViewControllers:vcs animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get to the main screen by using

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: It's not working.. I really dont have any clue why. and also, I just want to get to the previous view, not to the root view.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Debug your code snippet deeply. check in your array vcs, the objects are inserting? if yes then check `self.navigationController` is not nil.. if nothing then elaborate ur code. if u dont want to expose your code try alternative animation.

Try Using CATransition Animation effects.

```
CATransition * trans = [CATransition animation];
trans.type = kCATransitionPush;
trans.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
trans.duration = 0.22;
```