# How to dismiss viewcontroller and pop to root viewcontroller swift?

Tags: swift, popviewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

I have main TabbarController which holds ViewController(A).
From this A pushed another ViewController(B) using navigationController?.pushViewController
From B pushed another ViewController(C) using navigationController?.pushViewController
From C modally presented another ViewController(D).
From D when use taps button , it should dismiss D and popToRootViewController .

I googled similar questions, but couldn't find solution yet.

How can I do this?

Comment: Your question is very similar with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47322379/swift-how-to-dismiss-all-of-view-controllers-to-go-back-to-root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a protocol

```
protocol YourDelegate: class {
    func didDismiss()
}
```

In ViewController D, create a weak reference to the protocol

```
weak var delegate: YourDelegate?
```

In ViewController C, conform to the protocol and popToRootVC in the function

```
extension ViewControllerC: YourDelegate {
    func didDismiss() {
        self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController()
    }
}
```

Also in ViewController C, set ViewControllerD's delegate to self where you present the VC

```
//example:
let vcD = ViewControllerD()
vcD.delegate = self
self.navigationController.pushViewController(vcD, animated: true)
```

At last, in ViewController D, in your dismiss function closure, call the delegate function

```
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    self.delegate?.didDismiss()
}
```

Comment: Yeap it works.Thanks. but when ViewController D dismisses it shows ViewController C first, and pops to root viewcontroller. Is it possible to pop to rootviewController directly without any transitions when ViewController D dismisses?

Comment: No, but you could disable the transition animation: self.dismiss(animated: false)

Comment: Actually, maybe you could try to call the delegate function just before you dismiss instead of in the closure, maybe that will give it the desired behaviour:

self.delegate?.didDismiss()
self.dismiss(animated: true/false)

Comment: Yeah I think It looks better. thank you. Is delegate the best way to implement this?

Comment: Yes, protocols is most often the preferred way to communicate between viewControllers.