# How to dismiss multiple present view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, presentviewcontroller, dismissviewcontroller

If I have some flow of my application like this..

**navigation(vc1)** --pushed--> **vc2** --present--> **navigation(vc3)** --push--> **vc4** --push--> **vc5**

how to dismiss to vc2 ?

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47322379/swift-how-to-dismiss-all-of-view-controllers-to-go-back-to-root

Answer (score 0):

You can use `popToViewController`:

Basic setup:

```
let nav = UINavigationController()
let vc1 = UIViewController()
vc1.title = "vc1"
let vc2 = UIViewController()
vc2.title = "vc2"
let vc3 = UIViewController()
vc3.title = "vc3"
let vc4 = UIViewController()
vc4.title = "vc4"
nav.viewControllers = [vc1,vc2,vc3,vc4]
```

Then pop to `vc2` (which is at index `1` in the array):

```
let vcs = nav.viewControllers
nav.popToViewController(vcs[1], animated: true)
//OR, if you still have a reference to the view controller
nav.popToViewController(vc2, animated: true)
```