# How to dismiss and pop up a view controller in single click

Tags: ios, swift

I have 3 view controllers In the first view controller (ie. MydownloadViewController) i am using this to push to the another view controller.

```
  let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ImagePreviewViewController") as? ImagePreviewViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
```

and from the image preview controller

```
 let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DeletePopupViewController") as! DeletePopupViewController
 self.present(vc, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

and from the delete view controller I want to back in my download view controller for this i am doing this -:

```
 self.dismiss(animated: true, completion:  {
                if let  destinationVC =  presentingVC.navigationController?.viewControllers.filter({$0 is MyDownloadsViewController}).first {
                    presentingVC.navigationController?.popToViewController(destinationVC, animated: false)
                            }

               })
```

But nothing happens what is wrong with this code.

Comment: does this line of code run `presentingVC.navigationController?.popToViewController(destinationVC, animated: false)` ? Try by adding a breakpoint on that line.

Comment: No this line of code does not run

Comment: what is presentingVC?

Comment: let presentingVC = self.presentingViewController as! UINavigationController this is presenting vc @RajaKishan

Comment: i found nill when print presenting vc

Comment: by this time `presentingVC` is already deallocated, hence it is nil. I have one answer here on strategy to reach root view controller: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68127944/1619193

Comment: But i don't want to reach root view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your popup dismisses the presenting controller instance would be nil. You may need to hold the reference prior. You may need to do something like the one below.

```
let presentingController = self.presentingViewController
self.dismiss(animated: true) {
    if let navigationController = presentingController as? UINavigationController,
       let myDownloadsViewController = navigationController.viewControllers.first(
           where: { viewController in
               viewController is MyDownloadsViewController
           }
       ) {
       navigationController.popToViewController(myDownloadsViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController?.viewControllers ?? []
                for viewController in viewControllers {
                    if viewController == MyDownloadsViewController() {
                        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(viewController, animated: true)
                    }
                }
```

Comment: in view conroller there are 0 element