# UIKit Programmatically: Architecture For Nested Navigation

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have a bunch of screens in an app:

```
Login screen (NavigationController - rootViewController)
  |
  Tab bar navigation controller
   |
    -- Dashboard Screen (NavigationController)
        |
         -- Details Screen (Child of dashboard)
   |
    -- Recipes Screen(Navigation Controller)
```

So login screen is a UINavigationController, and after login I push a viewcontroller which is a UITabBarController, with 2 screens, each screen is a UINavigationController (Dashboard screen, and Recipes screen).

I am not sure this is the right way of navigation architecture, but it solves the problem of not showing the tab bar at the Login screen, and only after login the tab bar is showing up.

I have a logout button on the Dashboard screen, and I am trying to go all the way back to the Login screen, but it doesn't work as the Login screen isn't in the navigation stack.
How can I pop all the way back to the Login screen? Should I organize my navigation differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is:

1. You could `present` the `UITabBarController` from the first `UINavigationController` instead of pushing it
2. Then from your dashboard screen, you can `dismiss` to go back to the login screen

I have also outlined some more ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68127944/1619193) on how to manage some complex navigation flows