# How to navigate to UIViewController which is not present in navigationStack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have three UIViewControllers. I am navigating to VC3 from VC1. I want to navigate to VC2 if I click on cancel or done button from VC3.

I have added the VC2 controller to navigation stack programmatically.

```
    DocListViewController *temp1 = [[DocListViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DocListViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController addChildViewController: temp1];

    for (UIViewController *controllers in  self.navigationController.viewControllers) {

      if([controllers isKindOfClass: [DocListViewController class]]) {            

        DocListViewController *VC2ViewController = (DocListViewController*)controllers;
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:VC2ViewController animated:YES];            
      }
    }
```

Comment: what's wrong happening now? Where did you call `addChildViewController`? It should be called before pushing VC3

Comment: @Lavanya v gowda push VC2 before VC3 without animation in VC1 and just push VC3 with animation from VC1.

Comment: Pratik Sodha can you please tell me how to do it.

Comment: why dont u use pushViewController

Comment: Just simply psuh VC2 and VC3 from VC1. But VC2 push without animation. So, you can achieve your exact requirement.

Comment: See the next link. It may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273506/navigation-controller-loop/47278412#47278412

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing wrong here is adding it as child view controller,`addChildViewController` as it as a child of the current view controller does not add it in the navigation stack.

[image]

You need to insert the controller in you navigation stack before doing `popToViewcontroller`.

```
VC2 *temp1 = [[VC2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"DocListViewController" bundle:nil];
NSMutableArray *vcArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers] ;
[vcArray insertObject:temp1 atIndex:1]; // ** This index is `1` assuming you only have 2 controllers and we are pushing it in the middle,
// if you have many vc in navigation stack and just want to insert a new vc just before your current vc go with this:
/*
[vcArray insertObject:temp1 atIndex:vcArray.count - 2];
*/

self.navigationController.viewControllers = vcArray;
/* --- ** This part is also not needed:
  for (UIViewController *controllers in  self.navigationController.viewControllers) {
    if([controllers isKindOfClass: [DocListViewController class]]) {                   
       [self.navigationController popToViewController: controllers animated:YES];            
    }
}
*/
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:true];
```

Also: you don't need `VC2 *VC2ViewController = (VC2*)controllers;`
inside the `if` block as you only need a `UIViewController` type object for pop-ing.

I have just edited your code, get the project reference below

**Edit:**
Adding GitHub link for better reference:
[PlayingWithNavigation](https://github.com/subhajitregor/PlayingWithNavigation)

Comment: I am getting exception:                                                                                                                 
  1. Presenting view controllers on detached view controllers is discouraged <DocListViewController: 0x7fc9539cd000>.                                                                                                                                                        
  2. popToViewController:transition: called on <RCNavigationViewController 0x7fc952804000> while an existing transition or presentation is occurring; the navigation stack will not be updated.

Comment: It is perfectly working, I will share a GitHub link for the project I created.

Comment: You can check this:https://github.com/subhajitregor/PlayingWithNavigation I have uploaded a minimalistic demo code using the above code and 3 controllers

Comment: Tell me if you get any problems after this

Comment: VC2 and VC3 controllers are not present in storyboard in your PlayingWithNavigation project.

Comment: I didn't needed that for the example as no design required, as there is no controller in storyboard it will automatically create a new view for showing.

Running the project will make you understand.

Also just tapping the view will push and pop from navigation controller.

Comment: Do you need vc in storyboard then I can actually add them, if you need it for better understanding

Comment: Yes please add the controllers in storyboard. VC1 will be my rootviewController so once I click on cancel button in VC2 I can directly navigate it to VC1 right?

Comment: Added vc and buttons in story board also added comment in vc3, you can checkout the git hub link again @Lavanyavgowda

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to VC2 using pushviewContoller

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
VC2 * VC2View = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC2ID"]; // "VC2ID" is the storyboard Id of your view controller
[self.navigationController pushViewController:VC2View animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIViewController *vc2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController *vc3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc2 animated:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc3 animated:YES];
```

Try this.