# How to pop VC to jump previous two View Controllers using Swift Language?

Tags: ios, swift

I have 4 View Controllers: Welcome, SignUp, Login, Forgot Password. Welcome asks whether a user has an Account. If yes, user is expected to click Login button, otherwise user is expected to click SignUp button.

If user presses SignUp button, app will push to SignUp View Controller, user will fill the form and hit SignUp button. Click on that SignUp button should display Login VC. But instead it's back to Main VC that is Welcome.

```
//This is the SignUp Action Btn 

@IBAction func actSingUp(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginSB", bundle: nil)
    let signupvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC") as! LoginVC
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

}
```

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273506/navigation-controller-loop/47278412#47278412) may help to manipulate navigation stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are **pop**ping (going back to previous controller) instead of **push**ing (adding new) view controller. What you should do is:

```
@IBAction func actSingUp(_ sender: Any) {

   let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "LoginSB", bundle: nil)
   let signupvc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC") as! LoginVC

   // this step is optional, it will remove SignUp controller from navigation stack
   navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)

   // present login controller
   navigationController?.pushViewController(signupvc, animated: true)   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't make any sense. You create a new "loginVC", and then ignore it and do a pop.

If you want to push a new view controller onto the navigation stack, use a push, not a pop. (`pushViewController(_:animated:)`.)

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let loginVC = navigationController?.viewControllers.first(where: { $0 is LoginVC}) as? LoginVC else { return }

navigationController?.popToViewController(loginVC, animated: true)
```

Answer (score -2):

If  You need to pop 2 views

```
let vcs = self.navigationController!.viewControllers
let last2VC = vcs[vcs.count - 3] // if count = 4 then it will go to vc num 2 with index 1
self.navigationController?.popToViewController(last2VC,animated:true)
```

---

OR

```
 for vc in vcs {
   if vc is LoginVC {
      self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc,animated:true)
      break
    }
  }
```

Comment: terrible idea... why do you think accessing by index is a good idea at all??? and worse - with hard-coded 3 in it. What if your design changes? what if something else was in front?

Comment: @KirilS. if you gonna assume then this will change the answer also , the op said 4 vcs in stack there is no way to crash

Comment: @Sh_Khan Nothing in the question says that there are 4 VCs on stack. In fact, it says the opposite: "If user presses SignUp button (from Welcome), app will push to SignUp View Controller"